# I need help getting my enter button to work when clicked on with the mouse

Tags: java

I was able to clear text with the restart button but cant get the enter button to work when i click enter it with the mouse. If possible I was trying to add a Try Catch statment to catch any invalid input such as the user entering numbers or symbols. This isn't an issue as much as the enter button working though.

The Code is listed below:

```
//Import utilities for GUI

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Gui extends JFrame {
    private int Reset = 0; // Variable to reset
    private int number; // Get Number
    private JTextField guessInputJTextField; // User Input
    private JLabel prompt1JLabel; // 
    private JLabel prompt2JLabel; // 
    private JLabel messageJLabel; // Game Status
    private JButton newGameJButton; // Starts a New Game
    private JButton enterButton; // Enter Button
    private Color background; // Background Color

    // set up GUI and initialize values
    public Gui() {

        super("Thinking of a Number Game"); // Main Title of Program
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        background = Color.GREEN; // Set background to Green
        prompt1JLabel = new JLabel("I'm thinking of a number between 1-500, can you guess it?."); // Game Description
        add(prompt1JLabel);
        prompt2JLabel = new JLabel("Enter your Guess:"); // prompt user
        add(prompt2JLabel);
        guessInputJTextField = new JTextField(5); // Enter Guess
        guessInputJTextField.addActionListener(new GuessHandler());
        add(guessInputJTextField);
        messageJLabel = new JLabel("");
        add(messageJLabel);
        newGameJButton = new JButton("New Game"); // Create  a New Game Button
        add(newGameJButton); // add newGame button to JFrame

        enterButton = new JButton("Enter"); // Create a Enter Button
        add(enterButton); // add Enter button to JFrame

        Random generator = new Random(); //Random generator
        number = generator.nextInt(501) + 1; //Create a random number between 1-500
        newGameJButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { // Create inner class
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    guessInputJTextField.setText("");
                    Random generator = new Random();
                    messageJLabel.setText("");
                    guessInputJTextField.setEditable(true);
                } // end method actionPerformed
            } // end inner class
        ); // end call to addActionListener

        theGame(); // New Game
    } // end GuessGameFrame constructor

    // Choose A Random Number
    public void theGame() {
    } // end method theGame

    public void paint(Graphics g) { // Change background color
        super.paint(g);
        getContentPane().setBackground(background); // set background
    } // end method paint

    public JButton getEnterButton() {
        return enterButton;
    }

    public void setEnterButton(JButton enterButton) {
        this.enterButton = enterButton;
    }

    class GuessHandler implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int Guess;
            Guess = Integer.parseInt(guessInputJTextField.getText());
            if (Math.abs(number - Guess) < Math.abs(number - Reset)) {// Hotter
                getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            } else {// Colder
                getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);
            }

            Reset = Guess;

            if (Guess >= number) {
                messageJLabel.setText(Guess + " is TOO HIGH.");
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(messageJLabel);
            }

            if (Guess <= number) {
                messageJLabel.setText(Guess + " is TOO LOW.");
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(messageJLabel);

            } // end if

            if (Guess < number + 1 && Guess > number - 1) {
                getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                messageJLabel.setText(Guess + " is Correct! Click the New Game button to play again.");
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(messageJLabel);
                guessInputJTextField.setEditable(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't understand your question.

Comment: the enter button wont work in the GUI when i click it

Comment: If it doesn't work you have to explain what is the desired actions it must to perform.

Comment: Define "won't work"? Did you add any debug code to the ActionListener to see if the code is executed?

Comment: When i click on the enter button i want it to perform the same action and clicking the enter key

Comment: And what happens??? Again, did you add any debug code to your ActionListener to see if the ActionListener is invoked??? I don't see any `System.out.println(…)` statements in the code you posted to show that you did this. This is basic debugging that you do BEFORE asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

## Problem:

You haven't added `ActionListener` to `enterButton`.

## Solution:

Add an `ActionListener` to `enterButton`. You can add an existing `ActionListener` e.g.

```
enterButton.addActionListener(new GuessHandler());
```

or a new implementation of `ActionListener` as per your requirement.